# Помогите составить регулярное выражения для российских номеров

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно составить регулярное выражения для проверки номера. Формат только такой: +7 (999) 999-99-99. Вместо 9 - любая цифра.

Comment: Только не забывайте что бывает ещё и добавочный номер, а то часто его ввести нельзя, и я покупаю на других сайтах, ибо проще найти другую компанию чем думать куда вписать номер, не все ещё дают комментарии оставлять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот:

```
\+7 \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-8Fnb0pDVQP3O8CS)